# Перевод дробного числа из десятичной в b-систему счисления

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Условие задачи:
Перевести заданное дробное число из десятичной системы счисления в -ичную систему
счисления.
Формат входных данных
В первой строке входного файла записаны два целых числа  и  – основание системы счисления, в которую нужно перевести число, и максимальное количество знаков после
-ичной точки  (2 <=  <= 16, 1 <=  <= 20)  .
Во второй строке дана десятичная запись дробного числа  (0 <  < 1) .
Формат выходных данных
В выходной файл необходимо вывести представление числа  в -ичной системе счисления, не более чем с  знаками после точки. Выравнивающие нули не выводить. Цифры,
большие 9, выводить маленькими буквами латинского алфавита.
Дробную часть вычислять с точностью до 10^(−5).

Все вроде работает, но сервис, который проверяет, код выдает ошибку на 10 тесте (вроде это значит, что возникают ошибки с длинными числами). Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long b, k;
    long double n;
    char a[16]{ '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f' };
    string q;
    cin >> b >> k;
    cin >> n;
    cout << setprecision(30);
    long long s = n;
    long long g = s, c = 0;
    long double x = n - s;
    if (n < b)
        q += a[s];
    else
    {
        while (g != 0)
        {
            g /= b;
            c++;
        }
        for (long long i = c; i > 0; i--)

        {
            long long h = pow(b, i), j = pow(b, i - 1);
            q += a[s % h / j];
        }
    }
    q += '.';
    for (long long i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        long long h = trunc(x * b);
        q += a[h];
        x = x * b - trunc(x * b);
        if (x == 0)
            break;
    }
    cout << q;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Главная проблема в том, что я и сам не понимаю, что не так.

Comment: (2 6  6 16, 1 6  6 20) это  (2 <=  <= 16, 1 <=  <= 20);  
2 <= k <= 16;
Округлять последнюю цифру не надо;

Comment: 10^(−5) Как можно это использовать?

Comment: Если `b=16` и `k=20` то вам понадобится 80 бит точности. Вы храните исходное число в `double` - 53 бита точности. Например 0.1 не представимо точно в `double` и на выходе вы это заметите. Нормальное решение получится только если вы перестанете использовать `double`. Число надо вводить как строку, все вычисления делать в целых числах.

Comment: @Stanislav, как производить все вычисления в целых числах, если нужно перевести дробное число? Возможно, это глупый вопрос, но я правда не понимаю.

Comment: `0.12` -> `12 / 100` -> `36 / 100` -> `108 / 100` -> `1 + 8 / 100` -> `24 / 100` -> `72 / 100` -> `216 / 100` -> `2 + 16/100`.  Откуда `0.12` = `0.01002` в троичном виде.

Comment: @Stanislav с каким типом данных работаете? Число 0.01002 в каком типе данных представлено?

Comment: `12` и `100` - пара целых чисел которые строятся при посимвольном чтении десятичной дробной части. `0.01002` в памяти не представлено. Как только готова очередная цифра она идёт на печать.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 1):

Решение на целых числах. Десятичная дробь считывается как числитель (`n`) / знаменатель (`d`): `0.12345` -> `12345 / 100000`. Затем печатается целая часть выражения `b * n / d`. Числитель обновляется `n = b * n % d`. Повторяем `k` раз. Если числитель обнулился, цикл прерывается:

```
#include <iostream>

void get_fraction(unsigned long long &n, unsigned long long &d) {
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '.');
    n = 0;
    d = 1;
    char c;
    while (std::cin.get(c)) {
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
            n = 10 * n + (c - '0');
            d *= 10;
        } else {
            std::cin.unget();
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int b;
    int k;
    std::cin >> b >> k;
    unsigned long long n;
    unsigned long long d;
    get_fraction(n, d);
    std::cout << "0.";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        if (n == 0) {
            break;
        }
        n *= b;
        std::cout << "0123456789abcdef"[n / d];
        n %= d;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 convert-fraction.cpp
> echo 2 20 0.12345 | ./a.out 
> 0.00011111100110100110
>
> $ echo 16 20 0.12345 | ./a.out 
> 0.1f9a6b50b0f27bb2fec5
>
> $ echo 3 20 0.12 | ./a.out 
> 0.01002011022122021120
> ```

**P.S.** Алгоритм можно доработать так чтобы выдавалась дробь полной точности, та которая с периодом в круглых скобках.

**P.P.S.** Что делать с точностью `10^-5` я не знаю. Может быть это значит что надо читать не более пяти знаков десятичной дроби.